# How to add something to cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport outside of the *cdkVirtualFor="". While avoiding a secondary scroll bar on the page?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am able to set up my virtual scroll view port using Angular Material.  I have it loading new data as I scroll down.  But I would like to add a section at the very top of the list.  I don't want it to be stickied.  Just at the top?

I looked into using the main windows scroll bar but that issue never got resolved.

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13862

Here is the code that I am trying to use.

All of it works until I add the div with the class create-comment-section.  So with just the nz-card it is fine.  I don't want to move the create post section outside of it as then there are two scroll windows?

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
itemSize="200"
(scrolledIndexChange)="
    nextBatch(
        $event,
        (communityService?.wallPosts)[
            communityService?.wallPosts?.length - 1
        ]?.id
    )"
>
<div class="create-comment-section">
    <div class="header-section">
        <span>Create Post</span>
    </div>
    <div class="post-section">
        <textarea
            style="resize: none"
            rows="4"
            nz-input
            placeholder="Describe your experience"
        ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="other-options-section">
        <nz-upload>
            <button nz-button>
                <i nz-icon nzType="upload"></i><span>Click to Upload</span>
            </button>
        </nz-upload>
    </div>
</div>
<nz-card
    *cdkVirtualFor="
        let post of communityService?.wallPosts;
        let i = index;
        trackBy: trackByIdx
    "
>
    <nz-card-meta [nzAvatar]="avatarTemplate"></nz-card-meta>
    <ng-template #avatarTemplate>
        <nz-avatar
            *ngIf="post.imagePath !== null"
            nzSize="large"
            [nzSrc]="getImage(post.userId, post.imagePath)"
        ></nz-avatar>
        <nz-avatar
            nzSize="large"
            *ngIf="post.imagePath === null"
            nzIcon="user"
        ></nz-avatar>
    </ng-template>
</nz-card>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Are there alternatives besides the cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport?

I was looking at ngx-infinite-scroll

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll

But not sure if it recycles the items like the material virtual scroller.

EDIT:
The problem that I get is when I'm scrolling down it partially shows the create-comment-section each time a cell is re rendered at the top.  I am probably going to have to try ngx-infinite-scroll.  Does anybody know if it recycles the items?